# JPA standard property: how will a JPA provider create schema without knowing database system password?

Tags: jpa

JPA has a standard property

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas
```

that asks JPA provider to create a database(schema for oracle db) for schema-generation.

Creating database requires system password, but there is no such JPA property for db system password. How it works?

Answer (score 0):

JPA uses some database connection, and that one has username/password.
If you want JPA to create the schema it is assumed that the user for the connection has sufficient privileges.

If you do not like this for a production environment you can generate the SQL statements upfront (you'd have to tell the system which DB/dialect to use at generation time) and then have a DB admin execute that script prior to application deployment.